# Two monitors, part of one black

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, 23.04

Kubuntu 23.04

My left hand monitor is a 16+ year old Acer AL1716 1280x1024 connected via adapter from VGA into HDMI port. My right hand monitor is an Acer XB240H 1920x1080 on DisplayPort. Graphics card is NVidia 3060Ti. Using X11.

A week ago, there was a graphics glitch and since then, a portion of my right hand monitor is black, on the right hand side.

Everything operates as if the whole monitor is available. Icons and windows can be dragged in to the black area and back again. The mouse pointer displays above the black area.  If monitor rotated any setting besides landscape upright, the glitch disappears but always comes back when monitor orientation normal. Area black on right hand monitor is equal to width of left monitor, and if I open Display Configuration and switch position of monitors, the entire smaller screen is black and the full HD screen is normal.

If either monitor unplugged, other works OK.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it with some informed stabs at the GUI and CLI, in this order
Using Driver Manager in System Settings, I rolled back from Nvidia driver v535 to 525, this broke the kernel 6.2.0-33 so I booted to 6.2.0-32 (with the main issue still apparent) and removed 6.2.0-33 in CLI, rebooted and noted that driver still 535. So I rolled back to 470 and rebooted and the fault was gone!  Have now rolled forward to 535 again, had a sticky moment during driver update when the display output disappeared and I did a reset.  Booted back up OK. NVidia driver is 535, the issue is done, the kernel is still 6.2.0-32 might just leave it for the next kernel update.